# Can't run program after including <boost/asio.hpp>

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost-asio, udpclient

I'm trying to implement a simple UDP client using `boost/asio.hpp`.
Starting from a minimal program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <boost/asio.hpp>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

I'm able to build the project successfully (compilation and link). But when trying to run the program i'm getting:
[image]

This is caused by the `<boost/asio.hpp>` include. 
Without it, everything is fine What can be done? Thanks!

Comment: You should post the minimal solution necessary to cause your problem. If a simple "Hello World" program produces the error than post only that. There's no need for a massive program when a small one will do.

Comment: How does your system find the boost DLLs? Did you check your `PATH` environment variable?

Answer (score 1):

You are likely pulling in a runtime dependence on a dll because of boost's default implicit linking (using `#pragma comment(lib ...` statements). The easiest way to track this down is to use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on your executable. (Make sure you use the right 32 or 64-bit version of depends.)

Comment: or use the fusion logviewer and find out how the CRT is linked.